# Kafka consumer is reading a lot more bytes than expected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs, redpanda

**TLDR:** In essence, we produce about 800 kB/s while a consumer is reading 130 MB/s, which is more than 150 x what we produce ...

---

**A litte more detail.** We have a few Golang producers that write about 800 kB/s to a few topics in a Redpanda (Kafka) cluster. Then we have a few KafkaJS consumers, some of them are reading from a single topic while others are reading from multiple. All consumers process the messages they are expected to read, but one of consumers is reading more *data* than expcected. It reads about 130 MB/s.

[image: Write and read amount pr sec]

The image shows how much we read and write to the cluster.

I tried removing the consumer for a while, but adding it again just makes it climb back up to 100+ MB/s. When removing and adding the consumer quickly it jumps straight back to 100+ MB/s. When adding multiple consumers it just adds up. 200+ MB/s, 300+ MB/s etc.

I have asked around but haven't had any luck finding anyone with the same problem, also can't find anything wrong with the client code.

```js
 this.redpandaClient = new Kafka({
      brokers: [redpandaBrokerUrl],
      clientId: "time-series-storage-writer",
      logLevel: logLevel.ERROR,
    });

 this.redpandaConsumer = this.redpandaClient.consumer({
      groupId: `time-series-storage-writer`,
      maxBytes: 1048576,
      maxWaitTimeInMs: 1000,
      minBytes: 131072,
    });
```

```js
await redpandaClient.redpandaConsumer.run({
    eachBatch: measurementProcessingUseCases.eachBatchHandler,
    eachBatchAutoResolve: true,
  });
```

```js
eachBatchHandler = async ({
    batch,
    heartbeat,
    isRunning,
    isStale,
  }: EachBatchPayload): Promise<void> => {
    const measurements: RepositoryMeasurement[] = [];
    for (const message of batch.messages) {
      if (!isRunning() || isStale()) {
        break;
      }

      const measurement = this.preprocessMessage(message);
      measurements.push(measurement);
    }

    if (measurements.length > 0) {
      const chunks = this.divideMeasurementsIntoChunks(measurements);
      for (const chunk of chunks) {
        try {
          await this.config.timeSeriesRepository.storeMeasurements(chunk);
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(`An error occurred while storing: ${error}`);
        }
        await heartbeat();
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: You've configured `eachBatchAutoResolve: true,` but I don't see a call to `resolveOffset(message.offset)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handling batch, you will need to mark a message in the batch as processed. If not, it will always read from the last unresolved offset.

```
resolveOffset(message.offset)
await heartbeat()
```

Looks like it's trying to read from the beginning since there are no marked messages.
Example can be found in https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I thought I tried that but will give it a test tomorrow! One thing, since we process a chunk of messages I would have to modify your answer a bit, if you have suggestions or examples to point me to that would be much appreciated.

Comment: In that case, I would move the entire resolveOffset & await heartbeat after you've finished processing the chunks from one message. In case of any error, you can start from the msg again.

Comment: What do you mean? The chunks are made up of multiple messages.

Comment: I see, you where aggregating in the measurements.push(measurement). In that case, mark the resolved offset when you are done with it.

Comment: That would mean the last message.offset? or do all have to be resolved?

Comment: Can't get the "read bytes" down, unfortunately. Adding resolveOffset does not change much. Tried manually committing, but not able to get it down. Gonna try another lib.